# Angular 5 Dependency Injection - is there another way besides using constructor()?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have a service declared in my `module.ts` file to have an application-wide scope.  The way to access the instance of this service is to declare it as part of the constructor for the component class, like so, and the framework automatically wires it up:

```
export class ComponentBase implements OnInit {

  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }
}
```

My component class is one of several similar components, so they all share a common base class, and this constructor is on the base. I discovered that base constructors are not automatically required, so it is possible that a derived class ends up without a constructor (and without the dependency).

So, **is there another, more foolproof way to do it in the base class?**

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do. If you want all the derived classes to have access to the service, you can declare it as `protected` in the base class constructor.

Comment: @ConnorsFan It doesn't matter whether `protected` or `private`, it will not exist so long as the derived class fails to call the `super(...)` constructor.

Comment: But the base class constructor will be called if the derived class has no constructor. You talk about derived classes with a constructor but where `super(...)` is not called?

Comment: @ConnorsFan - apparently that is not the case. If there is no constructor in the derived class, then the base class constructor is not being called. I confirmed this through `console.log`. I originally thought otherwise, which is why the bug took a long time for me to track down.

Comment: I don't know how you implemented it, but it does work. Take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-11wi9q), where the `HelloComponent` is derived from the `BaseComponent`.

Comment: I’ll look again, but our site is not running on Stackblitz. This sounds like a bug in Angular or TypeScript or webpack tho.

Comment: I can add that I use that kind of component class derivation in my own projects (Angular 5 + webpack), with no problem. The services marked as `protected` are available in the derived classes.

Comment: I was expecting that to work, and was very surprised when it did not. Creating a constructor with a call to super()  resolved my problem.

Comment: @theMayer Your `ComponentBase` in the code above *doesn't* `extends Component`. Could that be the issue? When I remove that from the StackBlitz @ConnerFan built, it all stops working.

Comment: It has to extend component?

Comment: I use `extends Component` in my code (I don't remember why I had to do it originally). Now, I see that I can remove it from the stackblitz, and it will work if I also remove the call to `super()` in the `BaseComponent` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The injections are provided as a constructor parameters: 
- you can set the class directly, like this:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService)
```

- or using the injector:

  constructor(injector: Injector){
      this.myService = injector.get(MyService);
  }